# font-face working in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, font-face

Website us using this fonts css file and for some reason the correct fonts are being displayed only in Chrome, but not on Firefox or IE-

Can someone help us figure out what the problem could be and how we could fix this issue ?

Thanks

```
/*Museo Sans 100*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'museo_sans';
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-100-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-100-webfont.svg#museo_sans100') format('svg'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-100-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-100-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-100-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
/*Museo Sans 300*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'museo_sans';
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-300.eot');
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-300.svg#museo_sans300') format('svg'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-300.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-300.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
 /*Museo Sans 700 italic*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'museo_sans';
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-700italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-700italic-webfont.svg#museo_sans700_italic') format('svg'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-700italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-700italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-700italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;

}
/*Museo Sans 900*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'museo_sans';
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans_900-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans_900-webfont.svg#museo_sans900') format('svg'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans_900-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans_900-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans_900-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;

}
/*Avro*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arvo';
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-regular-webfont.svg#arvoregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arvo';
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-bold-webfont.svg#arvobold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
}
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'arvo';
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/arvo-italic-webfont.svg#arvoitalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {  
  font-family: "museosans-300";  
    src: url( 'http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-300.eot' ); /* IE */  
    src: local("museosans-300"), url( 'http://xxx.domain.com/fonts/museosans-300.ttf' ) format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the `.woff` file exists and then reload the website with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: What do you mean? Of course .woff exist and ctrl+F5 obviously isn't a solution here.

Comment: I mean't, There may be an issue while loading the `.woff` file or it may be an invalid/corrupt file link (I'm not sure). I suggested ctrl + f5 after making any changes.. just to prevent loading page from cache.

Answer (score 0):

font-faces are funny and I've heard the order can make a difference. I use this and have never had an issue:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family:'Name';
    src: url('fontName.eot');
    src: url('fontName.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fontName.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fontName.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fontName.svg#fontName') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
 }
```

If that doesn't work I would say your eot and woff files are probably corrupt. If you used a font-face generator that can happen. try it again or try a different one.